# Is it better to have a conditional variable and a mutex or just a mutex in a 2 thread situation

Tags: multithreading, posix, mutex

Is it better for a thread to block than to wait? Is there a difference?

Scenario 1 is just having Thread 2 hog global variable k until it is done with it. Scenario 2 presents more of a real-world multithreaded scenario with more than 2 threads.

Scenario 1:

```
global_var k = 1;

Thread1() 
{
    //preliminary work

    while (!done) 
    {
    mutex_lock(handshake_k);
    if (100 == k)
        done = true;

    mutex_unlock(handshake_k);
    }

   //continue executing
}


Thread2() {
    //preliminary work
    mutex_lock(handshake_k);
    for (i=0; i <= 100; i++)
        ++k; ;
    mutex_unlock(handshake_k);
}
```

Scenario 2:

```
global_var k = 1;

Thread1()
{
    //preliminary work
    while (!done)
    {
        mutex_lock(handshake_k);
        if (k < 100)
        {
            wait_cv(handshake_monitor_k);   //unlocks handshake_k
            //mutex exclusively locked here
        }

        else
            done = true;

        mutex_unlock(handshake_k);
    }
    //continue executing
}

Thread2()
{
    //preliminary work

    for (i=0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        mutex_lock(handshake_k);
        ++k; 
        mutex_unlock(handshake_k);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it doesn't much matter because it takes such a short time to count `k` to 100.

If, however, you were doing something that took some time, the 2nd would be more appropriate unless you knew, for sure, that `k` would have to reach 100 before anything happened.

In real life, you are not likely to know what the waiting threads will be doing while waiting. No need to hog all the CPU time in the 2nd thread in that case. Free things up now and then so the granularity of the CPU sharing is smaller. This is also useful in cases where Thread 1 is tied into some sort of GUI event handling.

Comment: Thanks Lee! I agree that scenario 1 seems unrealistic